# Unable to update Maven project in Spring Tool Suite

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-tool-suite

I am importing a working spring-boot project to my STS(spring tool suite), but while updating the maven project it giving me the below error:

Could not update project csdc-server(my project name works fine in eclipse) configuration
java.lang.NullPointerException.

I could able to run other projects in the workspace though.

[image]

Comment: Please file a bug report at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ide/issues and also paste the full stack trace from the exception, maybe with a few steps how to reproduce the issue and a sample project, if possible. You can find the full stack trace when you open the Error Log view in STS.

Comment: Thanks for your time Martin. I resolved it by deleting the files inside the .settings folder of the project and rebuilding the application.

Comment: Okay, great to hear that you got it working again and thanks for letting us know.